# Who invented WebDriver ThoughtWorks or Google?

Tags: webdriver

It's kind of late asking this question. But reason I'm posting it because information on these two links:

One says that it is Google's product and other says that it ThoughtWorks' product.

**It is Google's Product**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver

[image]

**It is ThoughtWorks product:**
[image]

Comment: The origins of Selenium dates back to 2004: http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/history.jsp.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of a software testing tool rather than about software testing

Answer (score 2):

Jason Huggins was the person who invented Selenium RC in 2004 as an Internal Tool at ThoughtWorks.

Latter on when peoples start noticing a lot of cons about Selenium RC (also called Selenium 1) like security, usability etc; So Jason Huggins and his team met Google in 2007  and they together started working on making Selenium more advance (also Called as Selenium 2) although in ThoughtsWorks Simon Stewart Continued on Working Selenium RC and developed a superior browser automation tool called WebDriver.

Then Jason Huggins from **Google** and Simon Stewart from **ThoughtWorks** combined their work and Selenium-Webdriver(also Called as Selenium 2) was Born.

Comment: Read question once again. WebDriver is Google's product or ThougtWorks'?? Why wiki link has two different info on same page?

Comment: Paul as I said ThoughtWorks and Google both Worked on Selenium RC and Devloped a more advanced Open Source Selenium Web driver, So credit can not be given to One, Right. But Google always takes this credits because of it's Brand in Market, Now who the hell will Give a Shit about ThoughtWorks in front of GOOGLE

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is an open source project. Since its begining in 2004 at ThoughtWorks with Jason Huggins building the Core mode as "JavaScriptTestRunner" for the testing, over the years many people have contributed and evolved from Selenium IDe to RC to Selenium WebDriver. It is not a Google Product, but yes many people working at Google have contributed to the project. You can find details of the history and contributors of Selenium [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/history.jsp) and [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/contributors.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

From Simon Stewart book [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html) how and why WebDriver came to be:

> Jason Huggins started the Selenium project in 2004 while working at ThoughtWorks
>
> While Selenium was being developed, another browser automation framework was brewing at ThoughtWorks: WebDriver.

WebDriver (first released in 2007) used different approach: Adapter pattern, (and Google significantly contributed to it from early stages).

> When WebDriver was released there were significant differences between it and Selenium RC.

Later in 2009, [both projects merged](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-webdriver.html) - posted by Simon Stewart on Google blog.

It is well worth to read the link to get better understanding what were the problems and obstacles to be solved, which inevitably shaped the solution.